Why does _CopyRecord get called in some cases with TMyRec but not others?
I'm working with a Delphi record type that includes both managed (e.g., string) and unmanaged fields. I've noticed different behaviors regarding calls to _CopyRecord depending on how I instantiate and use the record.
Here's the simplified version of my code:
type
  PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
  TMyRec = Record
    a: Single;
    b: Int64;
    c: string;  // Managed type
    constructor Create(const aParam: integer);
    class function CreateRec(const aParam: integer): TMyRec; static;
    //class operator Initialize(out Dest: TMyRec); 
    function setA(const value: Single): PMyRec;
    procedure DoSomething;
  End;

constructor TMyRec.Create(const aParam: integer);
begin
  self.a := 1;
  self.b := 3;
end;

class function TMyRec.CreateRec(const aParam: integer): TMyRec;
begin
  result.a := 1;
  result.b := 3;
end;

procedure TMyRec.DoSomething;
begin
  self.a := self.a + self.b;
end;

//class operator TMyRec.Initialize(out Dest: TMyRec);
//begin
//end;

function TMyRec.setA(const value: Single): PMyRec;
begin
  Self.a := value;
  Result := @Self;
end;

Now, here's what I've observed:

Call with Create:
TMyRec.Create(0).setA(0).DoSomething;

This results in a call to _CopyRecord.

Call with CreateRec:
TMyRec.CreateRec(0).setA(0).DoSomething;

This does not result in a call to _CopyRecord.

Call with Create and class operator Initialize uncommented:
MyRec.Create(0).setA(0).DoSomething;

Uncommenting the class operator Initialize eliminates the call to _CopyRecord.


Question

Why does _CopyRecord get called in the first scenario but not in the others?
How does the presence of class operator Initialize change this behavior?
What is the best practice for working with records in such cases to ensure performance and correctness?

I'm particularly curious about how class operator Initialize interacts with temporary records and whether there’s a way to avoid _CopyRecord in all cases without introducing unnecessary complexity.
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Probably this bug: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33455
